# How to select the li element when clicked with on input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

when i select lists, Enter the input value in the input. only javascript has a problem. javascript code if written correctly, the output runs reliably well.

```
My Table:
---------------------------
   Brand      |    Color  
---------------------------
   Apple      |    White  
---------------------------
   Sony       |    Black  
---------------------------

My Out:
---------------------------
   Apple       |    Black  
---------------------------
```

My HTML and Javascript are as follows:

```
<ul class="list-brand">
   <li data-txt="Apple">Apple</li>
   <li data-txt="Sony">Sony</li>
</ul>
<input class="type brand" value="Brand" type="text">

<ul class="list-color">
  <li data-txt="White">White</li>
  <li data-txt="Black">Black</li>
</ul>
<input class="type color" value="Color" type="text">
```

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  $('.type').val( $(this).attr('data-txt') )
});
```

Comment: `$('.type')` selects all elements with that class in the whole document, you need to limit this selection to the field that "belongs" to the current list - for example by going up to the parent of the clicked LI first, and then selecting the next `.type` sibling of that UL: `$(this).parent().next('.type').val( $(this).attr('data-txt'))`

Comment: @CBroe  a problem: if the list is active, if we click on the same active list again, the value in the input should be empty.

Comment: Then set the value depending on whether the element currently has the class or not: `.val( $(this).hasClass('active') ? $(this).attr('data-txt') : '' )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.val( $(this).hasClass('active') ? $(this).attr('data-txt') : '' )
```